# Calculate time it takes to reach a certain game score

Tags: javascript, html, css, security, game-development

we are currently forced for a school project to secure a browser based game. My group choosed the dino game. Our idea was to send the score the client reached and his needed time to the server where we would check if these two values are matching. But how would you calculate the time a Player would need for a certain score?! Is there a formula for that?

So how can the server reproduce or calculate the time it would take someone to reach a certain score and compare this with the users time?

Answer (score -1):

For example you can use Date.now() timestamp when user starts playing and the same Date.now() timestamp when player reaches the score. Difference is the time player spent to rich the score (in milliseconds).
The same way you can calculate how much score a second player can reach. Then, just compare those values.
But remember, if you gonna use setInerval () to call timestamp once in a second for example - this method not completely accurate. It has some drift.

Comment: how is this going to solve OP's question?

Comment: If you know hom much score you'll reach in 1 sec - you know how much time you need to reach some score. Doesn't it solves the problem?

Comment: Hi, seems like a didnt ask the right way. The thing is that the server would / should check if the needed time and the reached score are matching. So it should somehow calculate the needed time for the given score and compare this with the time the user needed.

Comment: @meAndrew _If you know hom much score you'll reach in 1 sec_ that is what OP is asking how to calculate... he knows the time not an average score per second to compare to

Comment: If the speed of dino is permanent and any jumps doesn't affect that, then:

Comment: The speed is changing with time but we dont know how to handle that.